# The meaning of "a something" in dictionaries

Tags: phrase-structure

I always came across this definition in dictionaries(a something) . When a dictionary uses ***a something*** instead of ***something***, does it mean I have to use countable noun?

For example : The title of this [phrase](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/more-less-much-of-a-something) is "more/less/much of ***a something***"

And the dictionary gives example about that phrase:

> 1- It was really more of ***a*** comment than ***a*** question.

Can I use uncountable nouns in that structure? For example:

> 2- The taste of the drink was more of wine than liquor.

Or do I have to use ***a*** before uncountable nouns:

> 2a- the taste of the drink was more of ***a*** wine than ***a***
>   liquor.

Or shouldn't I use this structure with uncountable nouns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited, because I got it wrong the first time.)

There are two very similar constructs here.

**More of an X than a Y** usually only takes countable noun phrases. (That's why your dictionary includes *a* in the example.) At least in my dialect, it works with uncountable nouns, but it's awkward. So #2 is possible but not natural.

However, there's a very similar construct **more X than Y**, which also works with uncountable nouns, and even with prepositional phrases. *Of* is a plausible preposition for talking about taste. So *more of wine than liquor* can be understood as taking two prepositional phrases: *more [of wine] than [of liquor]* (with the second *of* elided). This is the most obvious interpretation of #2. It's equivalent to *more like wine than liquor*.

#2a also works, because it's turning the uncountable nouns into countable nouns: *a wine* means *a kind of wine*. This is a plausible way to talk about the taste of a drink.

Comment: Thanks, but I still wondering why dictionaries use "a something" instead of "something" in some definitions,

Comment: Oops, my previous answer missed an important distinction between *more* and *more of*. I've edited it to fix that.